# Need to get divs from string based on matching class

Tags: php

I have a variable `$company_id = 8;` and a block of HTML content stored as a string called `all_content`:

```
<div class="company-id-8">
    Content One
</div>
<div class="company-id-9">
    Content Two
</div>
<div class="company-id-8">
    Content Three
</div>
<div class="company-id-3">
    Content Four
</div>
```

I need to remove all of the divs from `all_content` that don't match the current company ID class. So, once filtered, the above html should become:

```
<div class="company-id-8">
    Content One
</div>
<div class="company-id-8">
    Content Three
</div>
```

I have the following code to filter out divs that don't belong to the current company:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $full_message );
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname = "company-id-" . $company_id;
$nodes = $finder->query("//div[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
    $filtered_content .= ;
}
```

I can't seem to work out how to get my filtered `div` nodes back into the `filtered_content` string though?

How can I tidy this up and get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to do the following:

```
$filtered_content = "";
foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
    $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
    $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($node,true));
    $filtered_content .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML();
}
```

`filtered_content` ends up being a usable HTML string with the correct content.